# MemSQL total server memory on leaf node much lower than system memory

Tags: performance, memory, singlestore

I have a basic MemSQL set up with 1 aggregator and 1 leaf node on the same box, which is set up with 16Gb RAM. Looking at the "Total server memory" for the leaf node via the MemSQL Ops web UI, it is reporting 494.2Mb. My data is much larger than this number, wondering if this is impacting query performance.

I have run memsql-ops memsql-optimize --memory-percentage 100 in attempt set the cluster to use all of the physical memory available.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total server memory is current usage, not capacity - maximum_memory is capacity. For more info, see https://knowledgebase.memsql.com/hc/en-us/articles/208759276-What-is-using-memory-on-my-leaves-